# Is There any way to publish asp.net backend with html,css,js frontend application

Tags: asp.net, web, frontend, backend, publish

I created A full stack web app using visual studio code for frontend and visual studio for backend. I publsihed my backend and extracted files to plesk hosting. But I'm having htpp404 error. [Error I have] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mVKR.png) When I just uploaded frontend site worked properly. I think I publish my backend incorrectly. To SUMMARIZE how technologies interact with each other : First I start my swagger on localhost:7269 [Step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsDse.png) then I run my frontend to reach api url's with this url's my app retrives data [How I retrive data from backend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xcb0W.png) and frontend creates columns etc. [Step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJwcJ.png) Whole app works properly in my device but I can't run it online please help.

First I tried it on hostinger then I Changed to Plesk Everytime I try had same issues I only can run frontend online but It dosen't make any sense if app won't have backend unfortunatly.